# How does my Python point to Python3 without setting PATH?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

My mac came with Python2 by default. I installed Python3 using Homebrew (`brew install python3`) and did *something* to get `python` to point to `python3` in Terminal. Unfortunately I can't remember what I did (I must have casually copied and pasted a couple lines of commands to get `python` set to `python3`). Now that I want to find out what I did that was forgotten, I looked everywhere in my **$PATHS**, my **.bash_profile**, **.zhrc** etc but I found nothing set for python or python3 - no PATHs written, no aliasing either.

How is that possible and what else could I have done?

My Python versions:

```
my-mac:~ myname$ python2

Python 2.7.16 (default, Feb 28 2021, 12:34:25) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.19.59.6) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploy on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

my-mac:~ myname$ python

Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 05:25:02) 
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Here are all my **PATHs**:

```
my-mac:~ myname$ echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"

/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin
/Users/myname/.rvm/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/Users/myname/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin/
```

Checking Python and Python3 paths:

```
my-mac:~ myname$ type python
python is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python)

my-mac:~ myname$ type python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

My **.bash_profile** and **.zshrc** content:

```
my-mac:~ myname$ nano .bash_profile

export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

my-mac:~ myname$ nano .zshrc

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brew install the binaries at `/usr/local/bin` which is before `/usr/bin` in your PATH. (brew updates the PATH to include it prior to the systems `/usr/bin`). You don't need to do anything to put brew installed apps in your PATH, it's already there.

Try `which python` and see where it points. Here's an example of MacOS default interpreter.

```
➜ which python
/usr/bin/python
➜ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Jun 18 2021, 03:23:53)
[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.19.59.6) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploy on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
```

If you want python to point to the system's Python 2.x, you can delete `/usr/local/bin/python`. Then to use Python3, you'll need to specify `python3`. (which is located at `/usr/local/bin/`)

You can list `/usr/local/bin` which contains symlinks to the actual binaries.

```
➜ ll /usr/local/bin | grep python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 usr  admin    38B Sep  5 12:27 python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 usr  admin    45B Sep  5 12:27 python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 usr  admin    40B Sep  5 12:27 python3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/bin/python3.9
```

Comment: Ah I see. So the default python2 the mac came with is install in `/usr/bin` and Homebrew installed python3 `/usr/local/bin`.  My python created in `/usr/local/bin` is linked to `/usr/local/bin/python3` which came before the default `/usr/bin` path so the created python in `/usr/local/bin` is executed as python3 before the system python(2) in `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Should I keep it the current way (the PATH ordering) or is it better to alias it instead?

Comment: Keep it that way, otherwise you'll need to have an alias for every package you install with brew. If you want `python` to refer your system interpreter, just delete the symlink `/usr/local/bin/python`